# passing php object into array/list like in java

Tags: java, php, list, object

maybe its duplicate but i cant find it.

```
    something = new ArrayList<>(); 
something.add(new Object("Hello"));
something.add(new object("World"));
something.add(new Object("!"));
for(blablabla){
System.out.print(something.get(i).getTextFromConstructor());
}
```

this will print "Hello World!"

in php i dont know solution to pass whole objects into array to call their methods from loop or just by something[0]->method();
As  i know this in php cannnot be done, but maybe i am wrong :-)

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = new MyUSerDefinedObject("Hello");
//...

echo $arr[0]->methd();
//or
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    echo $val->methd();
}
```

Comment: lol it works? i tried it few years before but it does not worked. Thanks

Comment: ohh, with for it does not worked but with foreach yes.. thankyou

Comment: now i feel like begginer :D. Now i can write more object oriented php code

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to set the bridge b/w php and java so that you can pass values to them

```
<?php
$date = new Java("java.util.Date", 70, 9, 4);
var_dump($date->toString());
$map = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
$map->put("title", "Java Bridge!");
$map->put("when", $date);
echo $map->get("when")->toString()."\n";
echo $map->get("title")."\n";

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$map->put("stuff", $array);
var_dump($map->get("stuff"))."\n";

$system = new JavaClass("java.lang.System");
echo "OS: ".$system->getProperty("os.name")."\n";
$math = new JavaClass("java.lang.Math");
echo "PI: ".$math->PI."\n";
?>
```